# Laravel 5.4 - schedule:run works only once

Tags: laravel

I made a custom artisan command called `db:dump` which dumps my database into a `sql` file.

I tried applying it into a scheduler so it'll backup every time depending on the time range I want to apply. In this case, I tested it with `everyMinute()`

Here's what my Kernel look's like.

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\MySqlDump::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('db:dump') 
                  ->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

It only works once when I execute `php artisan schedule:run` in my command prompt. Tried waiting for 5 minutes to see if it will backup 5 times but it didn't. I tried running `schedule:run` repeatedly and that's when it only worked each time. Basically speaking, it dumps an `sql` file every time I run `schedule:run`.

I'm totally lost now, advanced thanks to those who can help me. :)

Comment: Did you add `* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` in your crontab?

Comment: Oh no, where can I find this `conrtab`?

Comment: Sorry. Is "crontab" whats your dev environment?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.4 and it's not online in a server. It's currently on localhost if that info helps.

Comment: Oh! But are you using Homestead or XAMPP?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP for MySQL.

Comment: @JanArielSanJose : which are you using as well as are you using UI for server accessing like CPanel .

Comment: @sunitiyadav I'm only using XAMPP for phpMyAdmin and MySQL.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

Comment: How can I use Cron if I'm only using XAMPP with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running locally, then you should use the following.

```
 php artisan schedule:work
```

When you are on a live server, you have to set the cron configuration like the following

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally

Answer (score 0):

You need to run cronjob on control panel plan servers like Plesk or directadmin or Cpanel.

egg:[visit](https://www.plothost.com/kb/working-cron-jobs-directadmin/)